# Visualization of the maximum distance point in rviz

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I create and build own node that calculate the maximal distance of the obstacle (based on laser data). I would like to visualize that point in rviz and distinguished with some colour(for example green). This is my launch file

```
<launch>
<param name="/use_sim_time" value="true"/>

<node name="rosplay" pkg="rosbag" type="play" args=" /Data/p1-20.bag --loop  --clock"/>

<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="baselink_laser" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /base_link /laser 10"/>
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="laser_imu" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /laser /base_imu 10"/>
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="baselink_camera" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /base_link /camera 10"/>

<!-- Start the map server node and specify the map file (*.pgm) and the map resolution in metres/pixel -->
<node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(find amcl_listener)/maps/pow_real_time.yaml"         output="screen"/>

<!--Start the Laser_scan_matcher package, to provide odometry from laser data (ICP)-->
<node pkg="laser_scan_matcher" type="laser_scan_matcher_node" 
    name="laser_scan_matcher_node" output="screen">
    <param name="use_alpha_beta" value="true"/>
    <param name="max_iterations" value="10"/>
</node>
```

```
<node pkg="amcl" type="amcl" name="amcl" respawn="true" output="screen">
    <param name="base_frame_id" value="base_link"/>
    <param name="odom_frame_id" value="world"/>
    <param name="global_frame_id" value="map"/>
    <param name="update_min_d" value="0.09"/>   
    <param name="update_min_a" value="0.09"/> 
    <param name="initial_pose_x" value="-1"/>
    <param name="initial_pose_y" value="0"/>
    <param name="initial_pose_a" value="-0.1"/>
    <param name="min_particles" value="6000"/> 
    <param name="max_particles" value="8000"/>
    <param name="odom_model_type" value="diff"/>
    <param name="kld_err" value="0.1"/> 
    <param name="resample_interval" value="1"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha1" value="0.2"/>   
    <param name="odom_alpha2" value="0.2"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha3" value="0.5"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha4" value="0.5"/>
    <param name="laser_max_beams" value="30"/>
</node>

<!--Start the "analyzer_packages"-->
<!-- acml_listener broadcasts markers for the position of the wheelchair, to visualize in Rviz-->
<node pkg="amcl_listener" type="amcl_pose_listener" name="amcl_listener" output="screen"/>
<!-- Object node records minimal ranges from laser, speed_node will record travel speed of wheelchair -->
<!--node pkg="pow_analyzer" type="object_node" name="object_node" output="screen"/> -->
<node pkg="pow_analyzer" type="max_range_node" name="max_range_node" output="screen"/>
<!--node pkg="pow_analyzer" type="speed_node" name="speed_node" output="screen"/> -->

<!-- Start an rviz node with a custom configuration for the viewpoint, map_server, trajectory, laser scans, etc -->
<node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" output="screen" name="rviz" args="-d $(find pow_analyzer)/launch/pow_rviz.vcg"/> 

</launch>
```

This is the source code of the max_range_node

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include "sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h"
#include <vector>

sensor_msgs::LaserScan laser_scan;
float min_range;
float max_range;

void scanCallback(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& msg)
{

    std::vector<float> laser;
    laser = msg->ranges;

    int size_laser = laser.size();
    for (int i=0;i<size_laser;i++){
        if (laser[i] < 0.01){
            laser[i] = 99999;
        }
        if (laser[i] > 45){
            laser[i] = 99999;
        }
    }

    min_range = 2; //Init closest point 
    max_range = 1; // Init maximal distance point
    int index_min; 
    int index_max; 

//find the closest point to the obstacle and the maximal distance to the //obstacle


    for (int i=0;i<size_laser;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<size_laser;j++){

        if (laser[i] < min_range){
        if (laser[j] > max_range) {
        min_range = laser[i];
        max_range = laser[j];
        index_min = i;
            index_max = j;

        ROS_INFO("Maximum Range = %f", max_range);
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            }
    

    for (int j=0;j<size_laser;j++){
    for (int k=0;k<size_laser;k++){

                if (laser[j] > min_range + 0.5){
            if (laser[k] > max_range + 0.5){
                        laser[j] = 0;
                laser[k] = 0;
                        }
                        }
                    }
                    }



    laser_scan = *msg;
    laser_scan.ranges.clear();
    laser_scan.ranges = laser;

}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    ros::init(argc, argv, "max_range_node");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ROS_INFO("Maximum Range = %f", max_range);
    ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("scan", 1000, scanCallback);
    ros::Publisher laser_pub = n.advertise<sensor_msgs::LaserScan>("closest_points", 100);

    ros::Rate loop_rate(10);

    while (ros::ok())
    {


        laser_pub.publish(laser_scan);

        ros::spinOnce();

        loop_rate.sleep();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40806/visualization-of-the-maximum-distance-point-in-rviz/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2012-08-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-08-07**:
What is max_range_node doing and how does it provide its data? What's the output of `rosnode info max_range_node`? By just seeing the launch file, it is hard to infer what all your nodes are doing without even having the documentation/sourcecode of these nodes.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-08-07**:
Ok. Just add the source code of the node. Max range just calculate the max distance of the obstacle of the laser range scan data,.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-08-07**:
I just want to mark (with some colour, for example green) this Maximum range, which is max_range calculated in the node I just post it.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-08-07**:
I just the max_range_node visualize. The other nodes are at the moment not important. Ok?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-08-08**:
Your code seems quite obscure. Are you sure it does what you want? You walk over the laser in nested loops. If you just want to get the max/min that is wrong.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-08-09**:
Ok. yes than its wrong. What should I do to get max/min?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-08-10**:
Well, usually it's: max=0; for(uint i ... laser.range) if(laser.range[i] > max: max=laser.range[i]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Given your purpose I'd suggest to use a visualization_msgs/Marker instead of a LaserScan. A LaserScan can only display complete data, not single beams. With a marker, you can choose specific points, select a color, and also increase the size of the marker.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-08-08**:
Ok. Thanks. How to use a visualization_msgs/Marker??Where to specify that?Do I need some extra code for the marker???

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-08-08**:
any example of  visualization_msgs/Marker and single beam like maximum range??

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-08-08**:
http://ros.org/wiki/visualization_msgs/Tutorials